# How does an optical chopper work?

Tags: optics, measurements, signal-processing

How is an [optical chopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_chopper) eliminating drift? Or in more concrete words: Why is a chopped signal eliminating drift (DC -> AC)?

[image]

Comment: In what context? Normally one would use the pulsed signal in conjunction with a lock-in amplifier to isolate whatever signal (change in experiment by the light) is being measured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chopper by itself does *not* eliminate drift, a chopper *and* a highpass (or bandpass) filter eliminate drift. The point of "chopping" is to place the information bearing signal from being near dc having low frequency content to be at a convenient so-called carrier frequency (for a chopper the "carrier frequency" is the rate of spinning times black lines)  that can be amplified, filtered (bandpass) and then demodulated/detected.

It is quite difficult to make an amplifier, or a general receiver chain, to work *accurately* at very low frequencies. The reason for this is that all instrumentation drift is itself low frequency and are caused by many external problems: temperature, aging, humidity, bias, etc. When the information is moved to a high frequency then these problems are suppressed by the bandpass filter as the drift is not "chopped" and stays at/near dc while the signal is around now the carrier.

Comment: This is a good answer. While not necessary, a chopper can also be used along with a [lock-in amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-in_amplifier)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of that highpass filter. I think I got it, at least conceptually but I'm afraid I'd need some visualized signal drawings where I can see the frequencies being separated to get it in detail. I also wonder about the "chopping frequency". There must be a certain frequency that is needed, or?

Comment: Maybe I'm not that smart but..  why isn't a highpass filter not doing the job alone?

Comment: I'm googling myself dead and can't find any source that provides basically more than 3-5 sentences..  can you advice me a good literature or something else? Good means easy to understand :)

Comment: Usually a highpass filter is "just" a capacitive coupling (capacitor in series) that removes dc before driving the input gate (or  base or grid) of the receiver amplifier but before you would detect the signal you want to minimize the high frequency noise too, hence a low pass filter (series inductor/shunt capacitance or something like that) is used before the rectifying. The highpass/lowpass combination is a bandpass filter.

Comment: As to the carrier frequency I do not know any fast  rules because you have several considerations including the noise the chopper creates, the internal receiver noise especially (1/f) types, its drift sensitivity, and ac (50/60 Hz and its harmonics) leaks, rectifier noise, etc. These set the lowest chopper frequency. The highest is as high you can spin the wheel, draw black/white lines, etc, the receiver's characteristic, etc.

Comment: The mathematics behind all this can be found under the heading "sampling", "shannon-whitaker sampling theorem" and such. A sampler is a frequency mixer, that is one that changes carrier frequency and that is what a chopper does, moves the signal from dc to something else. In practice, the frequency of chopping must be at least several times, say 5 to 10 times, or some such, the highest frequency content of the signal you are trying to detect. Since everything fluctuates, even your signal, you want to capture all that and you do not have a pure "dc" to detect.